# yii RBAC and yii controllers access rules

Tags: yii, controller, rbac, access-rules

I'm trying to customize RBAC, so I've made several roles for users.

Now I'm trying to  understand how to tell to controller which action should be accessed by which role.

In Controllers code I see this

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('create','update'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
```

Now I thought that 'users' meant to be user roles of RBAC, but I guess I'm totally wrong.
So on one hand I have this accessRules, and on the other Hand I have several roles of RBAC. How can I tell controller to use my roles ?

**Update for Jonny**

Sounds interesting....
I've made test action

```
public function actionNew()
    {
        echo 'TEST'; die;
```

then I've made rule accessible for all , just for test

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('create','update'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),


        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('new'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

But it's not working :( Any ideas why?

I'm getting

```
Error 403
You are not authorized to perform this action.
```

**UPDATE 2**

Ok test action works with * users.

Now I'm trying to connect it with my roles and I'm stuck there :(

```
array('allow',
        'actions'=>array('new'),
        'roles'=>array('role1'),
    ),
```

Is not working :(

on the page with button which calls this action I have rol checking code

```
if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('role1')){
    echo "hello, I'm role1";
}
```

**Last Update for Jonny**
Thanks for the help, I've finally did it.
I don't know why, but problem was that I must put all these new actions before deny array.

Like this

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('allow',
                'actions'=>array('new'),
                'roles'=>array('role1'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),



        );
    }
```

And in this case it works. Earlier my new action was located in code after 'deny' error, you can check the code fragments in upper updates. It's strange to me but now it works fine :)

Comment: Are those the full rules? I would normally just add the 'new' into the existing array where your index and view are. Check that works

Comment: Updated with full list of rules. Still doesn't work :(

Comment: You already have that statement for the `*` users. Remove it and add `new` into this line `'actions'=>array('index','view'),` The very first array of the rules

Comment: check update 2 please

Comment: NOw is the time I would use my answer to see if your roles are passing the checkAccess(). Depending on the biz rules you may need to pass additional parameters to the checkAccess() method. But that may well warrant another question as the scope of the question is changing

Comment: checkAccess works, I've updated my post to show how I check it.

Comment: No. From my test 'if' statement I receive 'echo' that my role is active, then I press the link to trigger action, and get Error 403
You are not authorized to perform this action.

Comment: Finally I've made it. Code is working. I've post it in update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to call something like this in your controller:

```
if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('my_user_role')){ // Do something }
```

`?` anonymous users

`@` logged-in users

`*` any user logged-in or not

`admin` is the username also, not a type of user in this case

In your case you can do this:

```
array('allow',
'actions'=>array('create','update'),
'users'=>array('@'),
'roles'=>array('myRole')
),
```

`users` specifies what type of user from the list mentioned above. The `roles` key then allows you to assign your specific role to that group of users

Comment: well this I understand, but I want to integrate my roles into that accessRules skeleton which is used in all controllers of this framework. At lest can you explain what is meant under 'users' there? Just usernames??? That 'admin' is username or what?

Comment: You mean the users key, so `*` and `@`?

Comment: yes *,@,admin, what are they ? I want to put there my roles so I'm trying to understand the logic of system, from where do it takes those *,@,admin, so I could hange them with my roles