# Yii - Custom access control criteria

Tags: php, yii, access-control

I am developing an application using Yii framework. I am in a situation where I want to create a custom filter. For example, the normal filters are like:

```
    array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('view'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
```

Now, in the array index for `users` you can only put `admin`, `@` or `*`. I wanted to know if it's possible to customize it in a way that not only these 3 parameters are used.
In my system, I have a set of user roles (which I have created in the database). There's one user called whose role is 'general'. He can only view some pages. There's another type of user with the role of 'business_admin' whose role can allow him to access his pages as well as the 'general' user's pages.

Could this be implemented by having:

```
    array('allow',
         'actions'=>'the_admin_actions',
         'users'=>'business_admin',
     ),
```

Please help!

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#role-based-access-control

Answer (score 1):

That wont work as you need `users` to be either `?` `*` or `@` unless you have an actual username called `business_admin` like the defualt Yii config has a hard coded 'admin' username. You can set up RBAC though and then add `'roles' => 'business_admin'`

This answer may help you [yii RBAC and yii controllers access rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513268/yii-rbac-and-yii-controllers-access-rules/22513360#22513360)